# Passing extra parameters to eightpoints/guzzle Client class (Symfony 4)

Tags: guzzle, symfony4

In a Symfony 4 project, I make use of `eightpoints/guzzle` bundle to make calls to a remote API. After installing the bundle (and configuring a client in a separate yaml file), I followed [this quide](https://github.com/8p/EightPointsGuzzleBundle/blob/HEAD/src/Resources/doc/autowiring-clients.md) to make my client autowired, which works perfectly. Then a extended my client class (i.e. the class descending from the `GuzzleHttp\Client`, the equivalent of the `ApiPaymentClient` class in the above guide) with some higher-level methods that take care of the calls I need, which also works great.

The question is: is there a way to make my client class accept extra parameters? Specifically, I'd like to define a parameter in the `parameters` section of my `services.yaml` and then bind it to a specific extra parameter in the client class constructor (which will then store the parameter value in a private variable for usage in the methods), i.e.

```
class MyClient extends GuzzleHttp\Client
{
    public function __construct($config, $apiKey)
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

Originally (i.e. as the result of the above-mentioned guide) the definition of the client service in `services.yaml` goes like this:

```
App\Client\MyClient: '@eight_points_guzzle.client.my_client'
```

which makes sure that `MyClient` gets the config defined within the

```
eight_points_guzzle:
    clients:
        my_client:
```

section in the separate bundle config file (`eight_points_guzzle.yaml`).

How do I alter the `App\Client\MyClient` service definition to accept an extra parameter and still get the config from `eight_points_guzzle.yaml`? So far I've managed one or the other work, but not both (i.e. making the binding work makes the client definition from `eight_points_guzzle.yaml` not be read, and vice versa.)

Bottom line: yes I can define the parameter as a class const in the MyClient class, but I don't like this solution; not mentioning the situation I will one day need to pass a service, not just a simple variable.

Comment: Did you find any good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was not to extend `GuzzleHttp\Client` but to inject it as a dependency into another service - wrapper and use that wrapper service.
So you'll need two services instead of one. First one is an extended `Guzzle` client configured like that:

```
eight_points_guzzle:
    clients:
        extended_guzzle:
           /*...*/
```

And the second one would be:

```
class MyClientWrapper
{
    public function __construct(
        ClientInterface $extendedGuzzleClient,
        $apiKey
    ) {
        $this->extendedGuzzleClient = $extendedGuzzleClient;
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    }
    
    public function request()
    {
       /*...*/
       return $this->extendedGuzzleClient->request();
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

Then you can use it were needed:

```
/*...*/
$this->myClientWrapper->request();
/*...*/
```

BTW if you'll name your guzzle client like `extended_guzzle` then you can inject it into your wrapper service like `ClientInterface $extendedGuzzleClient` and the autowiring will automatically wire it your service by naming.